# Drupal 7 Bartick Theme Title shows below body

Tags: entities

Drupal newbie here.  I have set up a site using Drupal 7 and the Batik theme.  On some pages the title shows up below the body and on some others it displays on top as I wish.  Is there a setting I am missing?  At this point it is mostly default settings.

Comment: Did you change the display order ?